# Scala iterate over a set of objects

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a sealed trait which is implemented by 3 objects

```
sealed trait MyTrait {
...
}
object A extends MyTrait { ... }
object B extends MyTrait { ... }
object C extends MyTrait { ... }
```

I'm using Scalaz's validation mechanism wherein the apply methods of the objects A, B and C return a validated type. the Objects A, B and C does contain some logic and I want to apply this logic sequentially, i.e., I want to first apply A and check what the result of A is and based on it, decide if I want to call B or just return the validated result. I want to repeat this until I hit C after which I just return whatever I get as a result of calling C.

Currently I have a static approach where I first call A, pass the result of A to a utility method and check for the result and then call B.

```
  def apply(request: Request): Validated[Result] = {
    val vResultA = run(request, A)
    val vResultB = if (isResultOk(vResultA)) run(request, B) else vResultA
    if (isResultOk(vResultB)) run(request, C) else vResultB
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions or any patterns that I can apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will define *succeeded results = results that are OK*, and *failed results = results that are not OK*.

First, `A`, `B`, and `C` are all objects extending `MyTrait`. Therefore, they can be grouped into an Array or a List of `MyTrait`.

```
val objects = Array(A, B, C) /* You can use List instead if you want. */
```

Then the type of `objects` is `Array[MyTrait]`.

Next, we have to iterate on this Array.
However, just calling `map` on this Array continues mapping even if the previous `isResultOk()` is `false`.
Therefore, we will use `Stream` instead of `Array`.

Let's see how using `Stream` can stop calling `map` if some condition is satisfied.

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(i => {
    println(i)
    i + 100
  }).takeWhile(_ <= 103).foreach(println(_))
```

The output of the above code will be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
101
102
103
```

So, `map()` ends, and then `takeWhile()` ends -- `takeWhile()` does not affect calling `map()`.
However, if we do the same operations on the `Stream`,

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toStream.map(i => {
    println(i)
    i + 100
  }).takeWhile(_ <= 103).foreach(println(_))
```

The output will be:

```
1
101
2
102
3
103
4
```

So the calling will be `map() -> takeWhile() -> foreach() -> map() -> takeWhile() -> ...`
At the end, 4 is printed, and 4 + 100 = 104 > 103 will be cut in `takeWhile()`.
The following elements will be not accessed further.

So, do we have to use takeWhile?

```
objects.toStream.map(run(request, _)).takeWhile(isResultOk(_))
```

This will get rid of failed results, even though we need the first failed result if failure occured.
(i.e. This will make a problem if there is any result that is not OK.)

How about the opposite function `dropWhile()`?

```
objects.toStream.map(run(request, _)).dropWhile(isResultOk(_))
```

This will get rid of all succeeded results, even though all results are succeeded.
(i.e. This will make a problem if all results are OK.)

So, we will use `span()`.
`c.span(p)` = `(c.takeWhile(p), c.dropWhile(p))`
We will test if there are results that are not OK.
If there is a result that is not OK, then we will return the first such result.
Otherwise, we will return the last result that is OK.

```
val (succ, fail) = objects.toStream.map(run(request, _)).span(isResultOk(_))
fail.headOption.getOrElse(succ.last)
```

`fail.headOption` will return `Some(fail's first element)` if `fail` is not empty, otherwise `None`.

In summary,

```
val objects = Array(A, B, C)

def apply(request: Request): Validated[Result] = {
  val (succ, fail) = objects.toStream.map(run(request, _)).span(isResultOk(_))
  fail.headOption.getOrElse(succ.last)
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage here of using Streams? How different are they from the Collection API?

Comment: Looks like the call happens only once with the Object A. Rather I want it to work in such a way that if Result of object A is false or failure, try the request with Object B and so on.